# displaying loading before modal load in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

Am loading a page in a modal popup and before the modal completely loads i would like to display a loading message which hides even when the modal is not completly loaded

This is what i have tried

```
$('#modaltrucks').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .before(function() {
             $.noty.closeAll(); 
          var n = noty({
          text: 'Loading ...',
               animation: {
                    open: {height: 'toggle'},
                    close: {height: 'toggle'},
                    easing: 'swing',
                    speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
                }
            });
        })

   //am trying to show the above noty before load

        .load("view-report-trucks", params)

 //after loading close the notif

        .after(function() {
           $.noty.closeAll(); 
        });
```

What is wrong

Comment: How are you actually loading the content into the modal? Is it all done via ajax? Have you considered having a general 'loading' message in the modal and hiding it once the content is loaded?

Comment: this line .load("view-report-trucks", params) does the loading, that is view-report-trucks is a controller in php code